# how to show mailmunch pop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i made form in mailmuch and got code from it , i added to webpage and its working with href , when user click show popup the form is showed. which is ok

```
<a href="#mailmunch-pop-123">show popup</a>
```

however now i have ajax request and i want this popup to be showed on ajax return success

```
<a href="#" onclick("getdata(4)")>show popup</a>
```

so any idea how to do it , because the form is rendered from mailmunch side although if it was in my webpage i should have used simple

```
$('#popup_id').show();
```

so how to handle this problem , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about how mailmunch code works I will assume that all you need to do is trigger a click on the first link within your ajax success:

```
$.post(url, data,function(){
     $('#mailmunch-pop-123').click();
})
```

Without more code provided it is hard to help more